# Change the css style of one element in javascript when you click on another element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change the background of a div that has an "input-group-addon" class, when I click in the input element:

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-12 col-md-5">
    <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail">Email address</label>
    <div class="input-group" >
        <div class="input-group-addon">
            <img src="pictures/email.png" alt="Email" />
        </div>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail" placeholder="Email Adress" onclick="changeBackground()">
    </div>
</div>
```

I create javascript file background.js:

```
function changeBackground() {
    var el = document.getElementsByClassName('input-group-addon');
    el.style.backgroundColor = "#cc0c8e";
}
```

and I inserted it at the end of the html file:

```
<script src="js/background.js"></script>
```

But it doesn't work. I had to make a mistake, but I did not see it...
Thank you in advance.

Comment: `el[0].style.backgroundColor` do this, because `getElementsByClassName` returns array of element with given class name

Comment: I think you have to add [0] to el in line el.style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName()` returns an [array-like object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName). To update an element you've to specify an index.

```
var el = document.getElementsByClassName('input-group-addon')[0];
```

Comment: It returns a HTMLCollection (an array like item)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem - getElementsByClassName returns array of elements

Just do it with:
`el[0].style.backgroundColor = '#cc0c8e';`

And you also can use `document.querySelector('.input-addon-group')` instead
`getElementsByClassName`